# How to save the results inside the reactive elements and use them after in further processing inside server.r

Tags: r, shiny

I have two reactive elements to read the data from the shiny GUI.

Now I need to save something inside those reactive elements and need to use in further processing inside the server.

This is my server.

Loads first file into R and stores in a file and the column names are defined as below.

```
 a <- reactive({
   fileinput1 <- input$file1
   if (is.null(fileinput1))
   return(NULL)
   #read.table(fileinput1$datapath, header = TRUE, col.names = c("Ei","Mi","hours","Nphy","Cphy","CHLphy","Nhet","Chet","Ndet","Cdet","DON","DOC","DIN","DIC","AT","dCCHO","TEPC","Ncocco","Ccocco","CHLcocco","PICcocco","par","Temp","Sal","co2atm","u10","dicfl","co2ppm","co2mol","pH"))
   read.table(fileinput1$datapath, header = TRUE, col.names =  c("Experiment","Mesocosm","Hour","Nphy","Cphy","CHLphy","Nhet","Chet","Ndet","Cdet","DON","DOC","DIN","DIC","AT","dCCHO","TEPC","Ncocco","Ccocco","CHLcocco","PICcocco","PAR","Temperature","Salinity","CO2atm","u10","DICflux","CO2ppm","CO2mol","pH"))
   #a$Chla <- a$CHLphy + a$CHLcocco  #Add new columns as per observation data
   #a$PON <- a$Nphy + a$Nhet + a$Ndet + a$Ncocco 
 })
```

Second file is uploaded and stored into b.

```
b <- reactive({
  #xlfile <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
  fileinput2 <- input$file2
      if (is.null(fileinput2))
        return(NULL)
      xlfile <- fileinput2$datapath
  wb <- loadWorkbook(xlfile)
  sheet_ct <- wb$getNumberOfSheets()
  for( i in 1:sheet_ct) {    #read the sheets into 3 separate dataframes (mydf_1, mydf_2, mydf3)
    print(i)
    variable_name <- sprintf('mydf_%s',i)
    assign(variable_name, read.xlsx(xlfile, sheetIndex=i))
  }
  colnames(mydf_1) <- names(mydf_3)
  colnames(mydf_2) <- names(mydf_3)
  full_data <- rbind(mydf_1[-1,],mydf_2[-1,],mydf_3[-1,]) #making one dataframe here
  b <- lapply(full_data,function(x) as.numeric(x))
})
```

Now I need to get the names of both `a()` and `b()` and create some extra vectors like below

```
var.observation <- reactive({
  var.model <- names(a())
  var.observation <- names(b())
})
var.both1 <- ({
  var.both1 <- c(var.model,var.observation())
})
var.both2 <- ({
  var.both2 <- Reduce(intersect,list(var.model,var.observation()))
})
```

--first The above method doesn't work.
--Second I cant preload the vectors var.observation, var.both1 and var.both2 from the home directory and load it from global.r because it should be dynamic and depends on the file input.

How can I create the extra vectors from the reactive elements output.
Please let me know if you have any idea. Thanks.

reactiveValues....

```
values$x <- names(a())
values$y <- names(b())
values <- reactiveValues (
  x = names(a()),
  y = names(b())
)
  var.model <- names(a())
  var.observation <- names(b())
  var.both1 <- c(isolate(values$x),isolate(values$y))
  var.both2 <- Reduce(intersect,list(isolate(values$x),isolate(values$y)))
```

still I am getting all the four objects are not found error.
How can I update these objects dynamically ?

Comment: Use `reactiveValues`

Comment: Have you tried just `var.observation<-reactive({names(b())})` ?

Comment: @JohnPaul...no it doesnt matter ultimately the output will be assigned to the var.observation in both cases. I am still stuck in using the rectiveValues...I am trying it now again...

Comment: @JohnPaul...The above method give this error..Error in as.vector(x, "list") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'

Comment: @jdharrison...I have tried reactiveValues and somehow its not working I have added the method I tried, please take a look and if possible please point me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to have multiple reactive elements to update the new objects.

To save multiple objects inside a reactive element, we can make use of list. and then we can call them inside a new reactive element to build on to the new objects.

```
vars <- reactive({  
  list(model = names(namesa()), observation = names(namesb()))
})
var.both1 <- reactive({
  c(vars()$model, vars()$observation)
})
var.both2 <- reactive({
  Reduce(intersect,list(vars()$model, vars()$observation))
})
```

I still did not explore much on reactiveValues but this problem can be handled with just reactive elements.